# MobileConnect tracking data to Sales Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, mobileconnect, sales-cloud, sync

Appears that getting tracking data from MobileConnect sends in Marketing Cloud to sync to Salesforce isn't supported out of box.

Has anyone figured out a good way to get this to SF, if possible at all?
If not possible, is it coming up in any future release?

Comment: Have you seen anything in a recent release? It would be nice if there was an IER version for Mobile

Comment: Hey Jackson, unfortunately not. I've re-checked about this with our AE as well and it isn't in the roadmap just yet, but they are aware of the demand. We solved it by using Automation Studio with SMS report data to create custom SMS History records in Sales Cloud. So far so good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, this is not possible - and the roadmap doesn't reveal an ETA for this feature.

The only way / best way to achieve this would be to use ampscript and a custom object for this - but be mindful of API limits and storage depending on your SMS volume.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for confirming this. This is what we were advised by external consulting company as well :)